# The GUI is not loading after installing xubuntu-desktop package for Ubuntu

Tags: boot, xubuntu, gui, raspberrypi

**Note: I posted the following in the Raspberry Pi forum and they directed me here.**

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I have followed the instructions outlined here:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview.

Everything works fine until I reach the steps for installing a GUI. I chose to use xubuntu-desktop. Once everything has finished installing, I type the command `sudo reboot`. The system reboots into the command line interface and then reaches the login prompt on the command line and then quickly disappears only to be replaced by a black screen.

I've tried blindly typing out the user name and password just in case the command line is not visible but nothing happens. It's just a black screen.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work? I've followed the steps in the tutorial closely twice now. I've searched online for fixes and I'm only finding how-to's for how to install Ubuntu or how to install GUIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the terminal pressing CTRL + ALT + F1 (F1 to F6) normally.
You may be able to access via SSH if you installed openssh.
If this give you too much trouble get the micro SD, mount it with the laptop and modify the files you may need to restore.
However if I were you, unless you enjoy investigating why it failed, I would just toast another micro SD and boot clean and use **ubuntu-desktop**.

Comment: Thank you Carles, I'll try your suggestion.